# Grothendieck group of the monoid of subsets in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The subsets of a group form a monoid, with the product of two subsets $A$ and $B$ the subset of all products ab with $a \in A$, $b\in B$, and identity the trivial subgroup. I'm wondering what its Grothendieck group should be. Is there an easy way to see it?

Addition: I'm not sure if I can make this a nontrivial question, but what if we suppose the group is abelian and disregard the empty set?

Comment: Usually one only defines the Grothendieck group of an *abelian* monoid.

Comment: Is the Grothendieck group defined for a noncommutative monoid?

Comment: "Grothendieck group" is defined only for abelian monoids; unless your original $G$ is abelian, your monoid is not abelian. You can consider the universal enveloping group instead, of course, but the answer is still what Mariano points out.

Comment: @jspecter: if $M$ is an arbitrary monoid, one can contruct the group $G(M)$ freely generated by letters $g_m$, $m\in M$, modulo the relations $g_1=1$ and $g_{m}g_{n}=g_{mn}$ for all $m$, $n\in M$. It solves the obvious universal problem. (But the implicit equivalence relation is more complicated to define than in the abelian case)

Comment: @Mariano: and it's not called the "Grothendieck group"...

Comment: @Arturo: I guess so, but having two names for the same thing is such a waste! Probably 'universal enveloping group' is a better choice for the general case, but it has less 'Grothendieck's in it :)

Comment: @Mariano: Certainly, having two names for the same thing is a waste; let's start by dropping the useless "monoid" and talk instead of "semigroups with identity" (-;. I suspect the reason for "Grothendieck group" is that the construction became known to a certain *large* group of mathematicians through the work of Grothendieck, even though the general construction was well-known among universal algebraists; and of course, the construction given by Grothendieck has the advantage of being very explicit instead of very abstractnonsensical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\emptyset\cdot A=\emptyset$ for all subsets $A\subseteq G$ of your group, the Grothendieck group of your monoid is trivial.

Comment: Would considering only nonempty sets change anything?

Comment: @Matt: No, since $A\cdot G = G$ for all nonempty $A$, so you still have a zero element.

Answer (score 9):

Grothendieck groups are usually only defined for commutative monoids, and your construction is not a commutative monoid unless your underlying group is abelian.

Nonetheless, you can define the **universal enveloping group** of an arbitrary monoid (which agrees with the Grothendieck group in the commutative monoid case). One way to obtain it is to take a presentation for the monoid *as a monoid*, and to consider the group that is presented by the same set of generators and of relations (that is, the same presentation, but now read as if it is a *group* presentation).

The universal enveloping group of $M$, $M_{\rm gp}$, is a group, together with a monoid homomorphism $q\colon M\to M_{\rm gp}$, such that for any group $H$ and any monoid homomorphism $a\colon M\to H$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $f\colon M_{\rm gp}\to H$ such that $a=fq$. (In other words, $M_{\rm gp}$ is the image of $M$ under the left adjoint of the forgetful functor $\mathcal{G}roup\to\mathcal{M}onoid$).

But in your situation, your monoid has a zero element: if you look at the collection of all subsets, then the empty set is a zero element. If you look at the collection of all *nonempty* subsets, then the whole group is a zero element. If you look at the collection of proper nonempty subsets, then it's not closed under multiplication (since you can have two proper subsets whose product equals the entire group).

And whenever you have a zero element, the universal enveloping group is trivial: suppose $M$ is a monoid with zero element $z$. If $H$ is a group, and $a\colon M\to H$ is a monoid homomorphism, then $a(z) = a(zz) = a(z)a(z)$, hence $a(z)=e$ must be the identity of $H$. But then for all $m\in M$ we have $a(m) = a(m)e = a(m)a(z) = a(mz) = a(z) = e$, so $a$ is the trivial map.

Thus, the trivial group $\{1\}$ with the trivial map $q\colon M\to\{1\}$ has the desired universal property for $M_{\rm gp}$, so $M_{\rm gp}$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Having a zero element seems like such a superficial roadblock, but in this case it seems there's really no way to get rid of it.

Comment: @Matt: The "problems" for enveloping groups come from lack of cancellation; any time you have a lack of cancellation in your monoid, that forces a collapse in the enveloping group. The case of a zero element is the most extreme case of a failure of cancellation, and it causes the most extreme case of collapse.