# name of the unit of adjunction between $-\times C$ and $\cdot^C$

Tags: logic, reference-request, category-theory, terminology, adjoint-functors

Answers to a earlier question about the [categorical interpretation of first-order quantification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467640/categorical-interpretation-of-quantification) led me to learn more about adjoints.  Now, I understand that a category $\mathscr{C}$ with products has exponentials if the $-\times X\colon \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$ functors have right adjoints.  For instance, the functor $-\times C \colon  \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$ takes each object $A$ to $A \times C$ and each arrow $f\colon A \to B$ to $f \times 1_C\colon A\times C \to B \times C$.  The right adjoint to this functor, $(\cdot)^C\colon \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$ takes each object $A$ to $A^C$ and each arrow $f\colon A \to B$ to $f^C\colon A^C \to B^C$.

The *counit* of this adjunction is a natural transformation $\epsilon\colon -\times C \circ (\cdot)^C \to 1_{\mathscr{C}}$, which is a family of arrows $\epsilon_{A,C}\colon A^C \times C \to A$.  These arrows are typically called evaluation or application arrows when speaking of programming language, or modus ponens arrows if looking at logics.

The *unit* of this adjunction is a natural transformation $\eta\colon 1_{\mathscr{C}}\to (\cdot)^C \circ - \times C$, which is a family of arrows $\eta_A\colon A \to (A \times C)^C$.  Are there any typical names for the unit of this adjunction and, if so, what are they?

Comment: In the last sentence do you mean unit instead of counit?

Comment: @StefanH. yes, I did indeed, and I've fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: My inbox tells me that there was a comment beginning with "I'd almost be inclined to call it $\lambda$ from $\lambda$-calculus, but that's not quite...", but since it's not appearing here, I'm guessing that it was deleted.  I agree that it's not quite $\lambda$, and the way that I've seen $\lambda$ used in notation regarding exponentials is that for an arrow $f \colon A \times C \to B$, the corresponding arrow is $\lambda f\colon A \to B^C$.

Comment: I used to call it $\lambda$, but I think it's probably better to call it something like $\mathsf{pair}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Perhaps this obvious, but it just hit me that the the arrow that I called $\lambda f$ is just the more general case;  this particular case is just the $\lambda \mathrm{id}_{A \times C}\colon A \to (A \times C)^C$.  I think you're right to call it $\lambda$ (or curry (see my answer)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit more thinking, and some insight triggered by the comments, I realized that if the category has some schema

$$\frac{f\colon A \times B \to C}{\phi(f)\colon A \to C^B}$$

the natural transformation arrow $\eta_A \colon A \to (A\times C)^C$ is simply $\phi(\mathrm{id}_{A \times C})$.  The question then is simply whether there's a name for this special case, which now doesn't seem quite as important, and what notation gets used for it.  Now that I know where to look, some notations have been easy to find, though I haven't seen mention of a particular name for the natural transformation.

#### Lambek & Scott: $(\cdot)^*$

Lambek & Scott ([*Introduction to higher-order categorical logic*, p. 51](http://books.google.com/books?id=6PY_emBeGjUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q&f=false)) call this:

$$(\mathrm{id}_{A \land C})^*\colon A \to (A \land C) \Leftarrow C$$

They use the notation $A \land C$ and $C \Leftarrow B$ rather than $A \times C$ and $B^C$, due of the logic-oriented direction of the book, but the superscript ${}^*$ is the point of interest, not the notations for the product and exponential.

#### Goldblatt ($\hat{\cdot}$) and Awodey ($\tilde{\cdot}$)

Goldblatt ([Topoi: The Categorial Analysis of Logic, pp. 70,71](http://books.google.com/books?id=AwLc-12-7LMC&lpg=PA71&dq=topoi%20%22is%20the%20product%20function%20described%22&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=topoi%20%22is%20the%20product%20function%20described%22&f=false)) denotes this type of arrow with $\hat\cdot$.  Specifically, for $g\colon C \times A \to B$, there is the arrow $\hat{g}\colon C \to B^A$, and so the unit would be

$$\widehat{\mathrm{id}_{A \times C}} \colon A \to (A \times C)^C$$

Awodey ([*Category Theory*, p. 107](http://books.google.com/books?id=IK_sIDI2TCwC&lpg=PP1&dq=awodey%20category%20theory&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=awodey%20category%20theory&f=false)) uses a similar notation with a ~:

$$\widetilde{\mathrm{id}_{A \times C}} \colon A \to (A \times C)^C$$

#### Computer Science: curry

[A question on Theoretical Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/17292) reminds us that in programming language theory, these types of arrow are called *curry* arrows:

$$\mathrm{curry}(\mathrm{id}_{A\times C})\colon A \to (A\times C)^C$$